# how to restrict users to directly load url in angular app

Tags: angular, angular-routing

There is url say:

students/student-profile/:id

I don't want users to go to this url directly. Instead If they try loading it directly I want to navigate to 'students/my-students'.

To achieve this I have created a service called previousRouteService:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, RouterEvent, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';


    @Injectable()
    export class PreviousRouteService {

      private previousUrl: string = undefined;
      private currentUrl: string = undefined;

      constructor(private router : Router) {
        this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
        router.events.subscribe(event => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {        
            this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
            this.currentUrl = event.url;
          };
        });
      }

      public getPreviousUrl(){
        return this.previousUrl;
      }

  canNavigateToProfile()
  {
    console.log('this.previousUrl', this.previousUrl)
    if(this.previousUrl === 'students/my-students')
    {
      return true
    }
    else
    {
      this.router.navigate(['students/my-students']);
      return false;
    }
  }


    }
```

then Created a gaurd within src/app/gaurds/post-login/student-profile/student-profile.gaurd.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PreviousRouteService } from '@app/services';

@Injectable()
export class StudentProfile implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private previousRoute: PreviousRouteService
    ) { }

    canActivate( next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

      return this.previousRoute.canNavigateToProfile();
    }
}
```

In lazyloaded module file:

```
     path: 'student-profile/:id',
        canActivate: [StudentProfile],
        loadChildren: 'app/views/student-post-login/student-profile/student-profile.module#PatientProfileModule'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ......
  ......
  providers: [studentProfile]
})
```

But when I try to navigate to student-profile/:id route through my-students route:

> core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[studentProfile ->
>   PreviousRouteService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[studentProfile -> PreviousRouteService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PreviousRouteService! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[studentProfile ->
>   PreviousRouteService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[studentProfile -> PreviousRouteService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PreviousRouteService!

If I remove usage of previousRouteService from patient-profile gaurd then this error goes away.

What could be the reason for this error and what is the best way to achieve such restriction where user can navigate to url abc through  url xyz else should be navigated to the xyz.

Answer (score 1):

add PreviousRouteService  to providers of your AppModule (app.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ......
  ......
  providers: [studentProfile, PreviousRouteService  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But this gaurd and service are to be used in lazy loaded module post-login-student.module.

Comment: you should move StudentProfile guard and PreviousRouteService  to the app module

Comment: Thanks. Can you also answer my other point in question. About restricting user to load url directly.

Comment: why need such restriction? explain more. it's not make sense for me.

Comment: Fartab Because right now our backend don't have service for student info. It send student info when we fetch list of my-students. So only if user navigate from my-students I can store specific student data within some service variable and then use it in student-profile

Comment: your solution (using route guard and router ) is correct. is there any problem?

Comment: I know it is better to have a separate backend service then doing all this. but at a time we don't have such service.

Comment: What is user want to refresh the page then also it will be landed to my-students page.

Comment: in the student-profile check the data is already requested or not

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help. I will implement the changes and will accept the answer. :)

Comment: Good luck Simer :)

Comment: Good lock Simer :)

Comment: When I refresh page values saved in variables do not persist.

Comment: Use localStorage or sessionStorage api to persist data between page reloads

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 6 then use below code or if you are using below version then yu have to add in there particular module in **Providers**,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterEvent, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})


 export class PreviousRouteService { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand rightly, you must declaring into providers where you are using it and exports, then you must declaring it into imports where you want to use it.

example:

exampleCreate.module:

```
@NgModule {
providers: [yourservice],
exports: [yourservice]
}
```

exampleWhereUse.module:

```
@NgModule {
imports: [exampleCreate.module]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.
but how about you check if id is null on your constructor? if is null then redirect to my-students?

Comment: masera ngelekanyo: Thanks for your answer. But I my question is different. I meant that I will always get :id in url but I don't want user to open student-profile/:id url directly as I fetch student data only in my-students. We don't have a service to fetch single student info. so I want user to navigate to student-profile/:id only from my-students page. Hope I am clear now. :)